# Do Unit Tests Increment Auto Number Fields?

Tags: unit-test, sandbox, auto-number

I just created a new object with an auto-number name field. Its `Starting Number` is `0`. I ran many unit tests before creating any data, and the true `Starting Number` I observed is `1420`. Is this observation consistent with platform behavior? Is it specific to sandboxes or does it also affect production?

Comment: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_apex_autonumber_sequence.htm

Comment: Sorry for the drive-by link only answer, was in the middle of something and couldn't provide a proper response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, autonumber field values will be incremented by unit tests. A new feature introduced in Spring '14 enables you to isolate autonumber values in tests from values used in production numbering.

Text from the [Spring '14 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_apex_autonumber_sequence.htm):

> A new option has been added to ensure that auto-number fields in your
>   organization's records don’t have gaps due to test records created in
>   Apex tests. This option isolates the auto-number sequence used in Apex
>   tests from the sequence used in your organization. As a result, the
>   creation of test data in Apex tests doesn't cause the sequence of
>   auto-number fields to be higher for new non-test records in your
>   organization.
>
> If this option isn’t enabled, there will be gaps in the auto-number
>   field whenever Apex tests create test records with auto-number fields.
>   For example, if Account has an auto-number field, and there are 50
>   account records in your organization, the field value of the last
>   created account can be N-0050. After running an Apex test that creates
>   five test accounts, this causes the auto-number sequence to be
>   increased by five even though these test records aren’t committed to
>   the database and are rolled back. Next time you create a non-test
>   account record, its auto-number field value will be N-0056 instead of
>   N-0051, hence, the gap in the sequence. If you enable this option
>   before running an Apex test that creates test data, the auto-number
>   sequence is preserved and the next non-test record will have a
>   contiguous auto-number value of N-0051.
>
> **> You can enable this option from Setup by clicking Develop | Apex Test
>   Execution | Options..., selecting Independent Auto-Number Sequence,
>   and clicking OK.**
>
> Note that gaps in the auto-number sequence can still occur in other
>   situations, for example, when triggers that attempt to insert new
>   records fail to execute and records are rolled back. In this case,
>   gaps can’t be completely avoided because, in the same transaction,
>   some records can be successfully inserted while others are rolled
>   back.